# Get custom post type where taxonomy..

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am not sure how to fetch specific custom post type where taxonomy is for example february. Generally I'm trying to have custom data based on months.

Registering custom post type

```
add_action( 'init', 'plants' );
function plants() {
    $args = array( labels and etc   );
    register_post_type( 'plants' , $args );
}
```

Registering taxonomy for custom post type

```
add_action('init', 'months');
function months() {
    $args =  array ( labels and etc );  
register_taxonomy('months', 'plants', $args);
}
```

Fetching data

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'plants'  ); 
$plants= new WP_Query($args);
if ($plants->have_posts()) : while ($plants->have_posts()): $plants->the_post(); ?>
           <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So everything so far works, I get 3 items. But how do I fetch only items with specific taxonomy? Following doesnt do anything

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'plants',
    'months'=>'february'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you are using the correct information. You can directly work with the query variables as you did. Just remember to reset your post data after your custom query, very very important!

You can also try using the `tax_query` in [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'plants',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
             'taxonomy' => 'months',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => 'february'
          )
       )
);
```

I want to however point out that you should [**regsiter your custom post type**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and [**taxonomy**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) inside the same function as you are currently creating multiple instances that is hooked to the same hook `init`

It is always important to keep your code organised. If you have 20 separate things you need to add to the `init` hook, create **one function**, and hook that to `init`. Don't create 20 separate functions. One thing to remember though, the order in which you add your functionalities inside your function is very important if one functionality depends on another. Adding them in reverse order will break your functionality

Also, when registering a new taxanomy, it is good pactice to use [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) to add that taxonomy your custom post type

> Better be safe than sorry when registering custom taxonomies for custom post types. Use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` right after the function to interconnect them. Else you could run into minetraps where the post type isn't attached inside filter callback that run during `parse_request` or `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: Wasn't this useful? If you solved your problem with your own solution, feel free to post you solution as an answer and accept it. If my solution worked, consider accepting my answer. Please help us keep this site constructive, not just for us, but for your sake and the sake of others. :-)